# zen-cart website url issue

Tags: php, web, zen-cart

Here is my website link http://www.littlefriendspetmemorial.com/ my problem is website has not more than 20 service pages but now each page is opening with http://littlefriendspetmemorial.com/index.php?

"**/index.php?**" with this query and now when i scan this website in Screaming Frog website showing more than 20,000 pages.

I think website is creating dynamic pages, i'm not that much technical kindly help me out for this what should i do?

How i create User/Google Friendly pages and their URLs.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to create human readable URLs in Zen Cart is done using modifications or contributions to the product.  If you look in the Plugins area on the forum https://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php, and search for "SEO URL" you'll see a few of them.

Bear in mind that there is disagreement about whether this is actually useful nowadays.  Most search engines can handle dynamic parameters.